# Why is this datatable showing no result when for a mobile number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a datatable in which I am putting my data. You can see the code below. I want you to notice that; the code will work perfectly right now. However, when you uncomment the Mobile# from the code & then try searching using profile-ids (8 or 12); it doesn't show the records as it shows without mobile number. I am wondering why.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $(".datatable").DataTable();
      });
    </script>
    <table class="datatable table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Profile id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
<!--          <th>Mobile#</th>-->
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Profile id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
<!--          <th>Mobile#</th>-->
        </tr>
      </tfoot>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Keller</td>
          <!--<td>12123123</td>-->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Donald</td>
          <td>Duck</td>
          <!--            <td>12123123</td>-->
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Fiddle link ... : [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/sxsouevj/)

Comment: Can you please explain what exact problem you're facing? In fact, the script only appears to work if I **uncomment** the phone nr (otherwise, it's all JavaScript errors in the console).

Comment: Possibly the formatting I did made it stop working when commented. Now the code runs in Chrome with or without commented mobile

Comment: When I do not add the mobile#; the search works.. else if I add the mobile#; the search doest work. This is the problem. I want the search to work after I add mobile# in the table. I dont understand the weirdness of Datatable.

Comment: What fiddle? There is no link to a fiddle

Comment: run snippet @mplungjan there is no fiddle

Comment: I AM running the snippet. It works with or without the commenting. Perhaps @Nevermore means snippet and not JSFiddle.net

Comment: if you uncomment mobile# and change in `<td>2312</td>` to `<td>asf</td>` then it works perfectly

Comment: i think it confuse between two column which has numeric value..isn't it?

Comment: look at this https://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/3371Lbnx/

Comment: Added a JSFiddle to the question

Comment: @debin I want a mobile number man .. does asf appear to be a mobile number? Nope.

Comment: I am just giving an example that datatable may b get confused between two column if it has numeric value..I know mobile number has numeric value

Comment: refer this: https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()
search on particular column..`$('#column3_search').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table
        .columns( 3 )
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
} );`

Comment: @debin You are correct. However, there must be some way to resolve this. This drove me nuts for 3 hours today :-D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100134/discussion-between-debin-and-nevermore).

Comment: you can check http://codepen.io/MWalid/pen/Jhlet as a reference

Comment: here is same as you want https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. I cannot see any issues in Chrome at least

I can search for phone 1,2,3, and id 8 to find John, phone 4,5,6 and id 9 to find Duck

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $(".datatable").DataTable();
      });
    </script>
    <table class="datatable table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Profile id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
          <th>Mobile#</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Profile id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
          <th>Mobile#</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Keller</td>
          <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>Donald</td>
          <td>Duck</td>
          <td>456</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: search '2' and '3' it gives first row..may b OP want to search on profile id

Comment: I have updated my snippet. Profile ID 8 or 9, phone number 123 or 456

Comment: again same problem search '5'..search is working on both mobile and profile id thats why its not working

Comment: Yes, it shows donald duck because he has 456 in the phone number

Comment: @mplungjan Funny part is.. if the number is already there in any of the fields; it wont get searched(my assumption) .. means if 1 or 2 are there in any other fields. They will throw redundancy error sorta exception or it just searches for both.

Comment: I do not understand what you see, I can search for phone 1,2,3, and id 8 to find John, phone 4,5,6 and id 9 to find Duck

Comment: OP wants to search only on profile id not on mobile number

Comment: Where in the description of the problem does it say that?

Comment: @debin The user can search based on any input.

Comment: Low threshold / input will not result in answers.. I will insist the user to enter more keywords. Fair enought. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the search fields searches in all td elements if it contains that value, possibly using regular expressions for this?

I haven't worked with DataTables, but is there a way to set which field it should check in? That would most likely solve your problem.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $(".datatable").DataTable();
      });
    </script>
    <table class="datatable table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Profile id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
          <th>Mobile#</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Profile id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Surname</th>
          <th>Mobile#</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Keller</td>
          <td>12123123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Donald</td>
          <td>Duck</td>
          <td>23232323</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: search 2 in searchbox

Comment: search for 1, it will work,

search for 2, the error shows up that the OP is having.

this explains what I'm trying to explain; it's searching for the search value in EVERY td element, regardless of the format. It just checks if the value you're searching for is present (possibly through regex).

Comment: @Kibo 2 is also there; why doesn't it find 2?

Comment: @Nevermore it does find 2, in both rows it finds the value 2 since DataTable uses regular expressions for the search.